# Error while creating plugin in Nop Commerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

This is my first demo project in Nopcommerce and i have tried to make my own plugin but during the time of Build some error is seen. Below are some codes.

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Aowi.Testimonial.Data
{
   public class TestimonialRecordObjectContext : DbContext , IDbContext
  {
    public TestimonialRecordObjectContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }

    #region Implementation of IDbContext

    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestimonialRecordMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public string CreateDatabaseInstallationScript()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
    }

    public void Install()
    {
        //It's required to set initializer to null (for SQL Server Compact).
        //otherwise, you'll get something like "The model backing the 'your context name' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"


     Database.SetInitializer<TestimonialRecordObjectContext>(null);
            Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(CreateDatabaseInstallationScript());
            SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Uninstall()
        {
            var dbScript = "DROP TABLE Testimonial";
            Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbScript);
            SaveChanges();
        }

        public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public System.Collections.Generic.IList<TEntity> ExecuteStoredProcedureList<TEntity>(string commandText, params object[] parameters) where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, bool doNotEnsureTransaction = false, int? timeout = null, params object[] parameters)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Dependency registrar part

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Aowi.Testimonial.Infastructure
 {
     public class DependencyRegistrar: IDependencyRegistrar
     {
         private const string CONTEXT_NAME ="nop_object_context_product_view_tracker";

    public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder, NopConfig config)
    {


        //data context
        this.RegisterPluginDataContext<TestimonialRecordObjectContext>(builder, CONTEXT_NAME);

        //override required repository with our custom context
        builder.RegisterType<EfRepository<TestimonialRecord>>()
            .As<IRepository<TestimonialRecord>>()
            .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDbContext>(CONTEXT_NAME))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
}
```

Even after cleaning and Building i am getting this error.
[image]

Can anyone help me with this. I have done all of this by watching a tutorial so if anyone can help me correct my mistake i will be really greatful.

Comment: No it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to implement this method and properties of `IDbContext` interface, which are described in error log, in your custom context.

for example, how it is done in one of the existing plugin Tax.CountryStateZip:

```
    public void Detach(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);
    }

    public virtual bool ProxyCreationEnabled
    {
        get { return this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled; }
        set { this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = value; }
    }

    public virtual bool AutoDetectChangesEnabled
    {
        get { return this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled; }
        set { this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot get an idea from your code that where is actual issue. But i suggest by an example.

make your install method code like:

```
public void Install()
{
    //create the table
    var dbScript = CreateDatabaseScript();
    Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbScript);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

Add a new class called `EfStartUpTask` and paste following code:

```
public class EfStartUpTask : IStartupTask
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            //It's required to set initializer to null (for SQL Server Compact).
            //otherwise, you'll get something like "The model backing the 'your context name' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"
            Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
        }

        public int Order
        {
            //ensure that this task is run first 
            get { return 0; }
        }
    }
```

And your `DependencyRegistrar` :

```
public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
{
        public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<YourService>().As<YourserviceInterface>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            //data context
            this.RegisterPluginDataContext<YourContext>(builder, "nop_object_context_product_view_tracker");

            //override required repository with our custom context
            builder.RegisterType<EfRepository<YourEntityClass>>()
                .As<IRepository<YourEntityClass>>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDbContext>("nop_object_context_product_view_tracker"))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }
    }
```

*Note: you have to change `YourContext` to your context name and same as for entity class*

Hope this helps!